# Is oData accepted across by developers outside of asp?

Tags: asp.net, open-source, odata

I'm working on developing API requirements.  oData looks very promising.  However, [searching for oData](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=odata) turns up results primarily related to ASP.NET.  Is oData widely accepted by the development community, (meaning php, Python, Ruby, etc.) or is it primarily used by Microsoft devs?

Thanks,

TK

Comment: StackOverflow is not a polling site, nor are primarily opinion based questions allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OData initially was an Microsoft project but now an OASIS standard and working towards becoming an ISO standard.  Besides Microsoft, OData is also adopted in many different companies like SAP, IBM and etc, you can check part of the OData ecosystem at http://www.odata.org/ecosystem/. Also there are library support in various platforms including PHP, Python, Ruby and etc, please check at   http://www.odata.org/libraries and you can search OData in GitHub.